# How to destroy tinyMce?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am using the latest version 3.4.b3. I have it in a dialog and it's contents are created dynamically.

So this means the textarea that tiny should bind itself to gets created every single time. So when I load up the dialog for the first time tiny shows up. If I load up the dialog a second time the dialog does not show up again.

So I think I need to destroy tiny on close of the dialog and then recreate it on load again.

I tried to use remove but I get this error

```
ReferenceError: t is not defined
http://localhost:3000/Site
Line 0
```

So not sure what that is all about.

Comment: I found it useful to just hide it, rather than destroy/recreate.

Comment: This sounds a bug that was introduced in 3.4.b3, and has since been fixed in the latest release.  Would you please try with 3.4.b2 or earlier and see if you've got the same issue.

Comment: @Rob Dawson - I tried the stable version and remove does seem to work. The only reason I am using the beta is I want to start using jquery 1.5.1 but in the change log I noticed that some things broke in older versions of tinymce

Comment: @James Black - The problem is not hiding it. But the fact that once the dialog the stuff in the dialog is gone. The next time they load up the dialog a ajax request is made to grab a partial view that re-renders all controls.

Comment: @Rob Dawson  - I thought 3.4.b3 was the latest. Where can I get the latest and how stable is it?

Comment: 3.4.b3 is the latest.  There's been a fix in head that fixes this.  If you're game, the latest in github is pretty stable, getting close to a 3.4 release. Try pulling from: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should shut down tinymce correctly in order to be able to reinitialize a tinymce editor with the same id as the first one.

To shut down an edtor instance use:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true,'editor_id');
```

To reinitialize use

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl',true,'editor_id');
```

Comment: you need to replace 'editor_id' with the id of your textarea (if your textarea does not have an id, tinymce editor will use 'content' as editor id)

Comment: @chobo and the `id` must be exact. I'll just edit the answer to reflect this idea.