# Any better ways of doing this jQuery setInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am wondering if this a better replacement to this code to make it look less hacky:

```
active_tiny_editor = setInterval(function () {
if(tinyMCE.activeEditor!==null){
    my_object.switch_tabs('tmce');
    clearInterval(active_tiny_editor);
}
}, 200);
```

Ideally the problem is that after page reload, the Wordpress visual editor is gone. I need to switch back to text mode and again to visual editor to see the content..

It looks like something doesn't get initialized correctly on the page after the first load and it gets fixed when switching editing modes.

Please let me know if you have some idea. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

This is the code:

```
            // select active editor tab
            switch(bootstrap_config_object.editor_active_tab)
            {
                case 0:
                    bootstrap_object.switch_tabs('html');                        
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if(bootstrap_config_object.tmce_editor_status==1){                          
                        active_tiny_editor = setInterval(function () {                              
                            if(tinyMCE.activeEditor!==null){                                    
                                bootstrap_object.switch_tabs('tmce');
                                clearInterval(active_tiny_editor);                                    
                            }
                        }, 200);
                    }else{                          
                        bootstrap_object.switch_tabs('html');                            
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:                     
                    bootstrap_object.switch_tabs('syntax');                        
                    myCodeMirror.refresh();
                    break;
            }
```

Then this is the bootstrap_object containing the switching tabs logic:

```
switch_tabs: function(do_active) {// switch active tabs   
    switch(do_active)
    {
        case 'html':                
            jQuery('#content-html').addClass('switch-html');
            jQuery('#content-bootstrap').removeClass('switch-bootstrap');
            jQuery('#wrap-code-bootstrap, #codemirror-insert-media').addClass('element-hide');
            jQuery('#content, #ed_toolbar, .insert-media, #content-resize-handle').removeClass('element-hide');
            jQuery('#wp-content-wrap').addClass('html-active').removeClass('syntax-active').removeClass('tmce-active');

            jQuery('#content').show();
            jQuery('#content_parent, .CodeMirror').hide();               

            if(bootstrap_config_object.codemirror_status==1){                   
                bootstrap_object.replase_shortcode_add_method('normal');
            }
            break;
        case 'tmce':                
                            active_tiny_editor = setInterval(function () {
                            if(tinyMCE.activeEditor!==null){
                                jQuery('#content_parent').show();
                                clearInterval(active_tiny_editor);
                            }
                        }, 200);                
            jQuery('#content-tmce').addClass('switch-tmce');
            jQuery('#content-bootstrap').removeClass('switch-bootstrap');
            jQuery('#wrap-code-bootstrap, #content, #ed_toolbar, #codemirror-insert-media').addClass('element-hide');
            jQuery('#content_parent, .insert-media, #content-resize-handle').removeClass('element-hide');
            jQuery('#wp-content-wrap').addClass('tmce-active').removeClass('syntax-active').removeClass('html-active');

            jQuery('#content_parent').show();
            jQuery('.CodeMirror, #content').hide();

            if(bootstrap_config_object.codemirror_status==1){                   
                bootstrap_object.replase_shortcode_add_method('normal');
            }
            break;
        case 'syntax':              
            jQuery('#content-bootstrap').addClass('switch-bootstrap');
            jQuery('.wp-switch-editor').removeClass('switch-tmce switch-html');
            jQuery('#content_parent, #content, #ed_toolbar, .insert-media, #content-resize-handle').addClass('element-hide');
            jQuery('#wrap-code-bootstrap, #codemirror-insert-media').removeClass('element-hide');
            jQuery('#wp-content-wrap').addClass('syntax-active').removeClass('tmce-active').removeClass('html-active');

            jQuery('.CodeMirror').show();
            jQuery('#content_parent, #content').hide();

            // resize codemirror 
            wp_settings = bootstrap_object.URLToArray(jQuery.cookie("wp-settings-"+bootstrap_config_object.user_id));
            if(wp_settings){                    
                jQuery('.CodeMirror').css('height', parseInt(wp_settings['ed_size'])+30+'px');
            }
            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'content');

            if(bootstrap_config_object.codemirror_status==1){
                bootstrap_object.replase_shortcode_add_method('syntax');                    
            }
            break;
    }
    // set active tab        
    jQuery('#editor-active-tab').val(do_active);
```

THe functionality:

I have three editing tabs in the WP editor, the traditional Visual and Text editor in WP. Then I add a new one called "Syntax" which will transformed the editor to show the syntax HTML using Code Mirror. I need them to be consistent and stable when it comes to using it and adding shortcodes, etc.

Comment: if you only need it once just use `setTimeout` so you don't need to assign it and clear it

Comment: I think I'm using them multiple times in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tinyMCE.activeEditor` gets set when a user clicks into a tinymce editor instance. Problem here will be that a page reload will only remove the html nodes but not the editor itself.
Before initializing an editor with the same id you first need to shut down that tinymce instance correctly. See this SO thread: [How to destroy tinyMce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162978/how-to-destroy-tinymce)

Btw. if possible it is better to use `tinymce.get('your_editor_id')` than to use `tinyMCE.activeEditor`. `tinymce.get('your_editor_id')` is always set/usable in case it got initialized.

There should be no `setInterval` necessary at all.

Comment: Thanks Thariama, it is very interesting. I don't know about this one..Can I post my code in details in other thread so you can see it exactly? Then I will mark your answer as the correct..Cheers.

Comment: it might be better to update your own question with your code

Comment: I have updated my question with the code. I hope its now clear. I believe that hacky code has some side effects when other plugins has its shortcode button in the editor (in WP, like when you click on it in the editor buttons, shortcode will be added to editor). When I clicked on them, they are not working and not added to the editor. Thanks. I believe there is a better solution to that. I appreciate your help. Cheers.

Comment: hmm, you want to switch the tab in case tinyMCE.activeEditor is set?

Comment: Yes..I have tried adding tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true,'content'); just before switching tabs but the switching mechanism seems unstable.

Comment: what do you mean by "unstable"

Comment: you are not calling mceAddControl anywhere? are the html source elements visible when you try to initialize the editor?

Comment: Yes I'm not yet adding mceAddControl..I'm a bit confused where to add it as of the moment.The code you see in my question is the original one, not yet added with mceAddControl or mceRemove control.I appreciate it if you can provide some tips.

Comment: Unstable means that sometimes the editor will appear and sometimes not..For example if I save the post in Visual editor, then after saving it I click Syntax mode and it is not loaded, seems TinyMCE is not working. same with text mode.

Comment: About your question. yes the HTML source code elements are visible in the HTML source code but the text area is hidden.

Comment: i mean BEFORE the tinymce instances are initialized. the textarea should be visible then. after tinycme initialization the textarea will be hidden (thats the normal procedure)

Answer (score 0):

looks better? :

```
function checknSwitch() {  
    if(tinyMCE.activeEditor!==null) my_object.switch_tabs('tmce');
}

setTimeout(checknSwitch, 200);
```

Comment: equivalent to setInterval & clearing the interval, the very first time

Comment: OP clear interval only if `tinyMCE.activeEditor!==null`. Your solution run once even `tinyMCE.activeEditor===null`

Comment: Thanks Loxxy, but I think there is a better way than not using setTimeout. I have posted my updated code.